# FTPClient download corrupted file

Tags: java, ftp

When download file from ftp server via `FTPClient` class files comes corrupted check for initial file **(img1)** and downloaded file **(img2)**

Source:

```
public class FtpClient extends FTPClient {

private String host;
private int port;
private String username;
private String password;
private boolean connected;

public FtpClient(String host, int port, String username, String password) {
    this.host = host;
    this.port = port;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;

    connected = connect();
}


private void verifyConnection() throws ConnectionException {
    if(!connected){
        ConnectionException ex = new ConnectionException();
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        throw ex;
    }
}


private boolean connect(){
    try {
        //try to connect
        connect(host, port);

        if(!login(username, password)){
            logout();
            return false;
        }

        int reply = getReplyCode();

        if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){
            disconnect();
            return false;
        }
        enterRemotePassiveMode();
        setFileTransferMode(BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        setFileType(BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        log.debug("Remote system is " + getSystemType());
        log.debug("Current directory is " + printWorkingDirectory());

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }
}

public void get(String batchName, String fileName) throws IOException, ConnectionException {
    verifyConnection();
    File file = new File("/tmp/" + batchName);

    if (!file.exists()){
        boolean mkdir = file.mkdir();
        log.info("Create batch directory '{}' result: {}",batchName,  mkdir);
    }
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/" + batchName + "/" + fileName);
    boolean result = retrieveFile(batchName + "/" + fileName, outputStream);

    log.debug("Retrieve file {}, result: {}", batchName + "/" + fileName, result);
    outputStream.close();
}
}
```

img1
[image: img1]

img2
[image: img2]

What is going wrong?

Comment: Interesting! Try flushing the OutputStream before closing it.

Comment: Have you compared the files (in size mostly as JPEG is not the more readable format ;) ). I would guess there is some data missing cause that offset

Comment: @AxelH I compared those files and size is same.

Comment: Did you check the content or the properties ? The same bytes count would tell me the transfert is correct. Some blocks might have been switch (asynchronous  maybe, I don't know Apache FTPClient...). You could use a merge tool to compare the content (have fun ;) )

Comment: @AxelH ha-ha fun, I wanna cry :D. It's clear that blocks are copied incorrect. I'll find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an incorrect CONSTANT for [`FTPClient.setFileTransferMode`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#setFileTransferMode(int)).

```
setFileTransferMode(BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Like the doc says :

> mode - The new transfer mode to use (one of the FTP class _TRANSFER_MODE constants).

You can use one of those :

- `FTP.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE`
- `FTP.COMPRESSED_TRANSFER_MODE`
- `FTP.STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE`

This will probably correct your problem of transfer, since your are using a value that could be anything ...

You are passing a value of `2` where it is expecting one of `[10|11|12]`. So It probably keep the default `STREAM_TRANSFER_MODE` value.